# Customize TableViewCell Moving Grabber

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableView where the cells are movable. In edit mode, that brings up the image on the right that you can grab to move around cells. This works fine. However, I would like to customize it a little bit so that instead of that image you could grab from anywhere on the cell. Is there a way to do this without completely scrapping apples built in moving and building your own? Maybe using a pan gesture recognizer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for you, [FMMoveTableView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/fmmovetableview) was just put up on github. It allows any table to be reordered by simply tapping and holding on a cell.